# Excel: How to efficiently check whether a selected cell is referenced in any other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, cross-reference

I want to check whether a selected cell ( say A1) is referenced in any other cell in the sheet I’m working in? Is there a similar tool that shows you arrows from the selected formula to referenced cell, but the other way round? Eg. A1 is my constant and I’d like to see where in the spreadsheet it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like formula auditing.

See [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/understanding-excel-2010s-formula-auditing-tools.html) and [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/formula-auditing.html) for more info.

From the 2nd link and your comment, I can determine that what you were referring to is Trace Dependents. Quoting from the source:

> Trace Dependents
>
> To show arrows that indicate which cells use a selected cell, execute
>   the following steps.
>
> 1. Select cell C12.
> 2. On the Formulas tab, in the Formula Auditing group, click Trace Dependents.
>
> [image: Trace Dependents]
>
> Result:
>
> [image: Trace Dependents Result]
>
> As expected, Group size is used to calculate the Cost per person.

It works whether the cell has a constant or a formula, mainly because Excel can figure out where the formulas are and what cells do they refer to.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard, no worries mate. Let's delete our comments as they're not going to help any one  :)